# Multiple import requests from same url

Tags: python, stock

I would like to download float data of stocks using the following code, which then has to write to a json file.

```
import requests
import json

filename='float.json'

url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/stats"   
response = requests.get(url).json()
data = (response['symbol'], response['float'])

with open(filename, 'a+') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Now i would like to download the data for multiple stocks, so where it says "aapl" in the url, i would like to have mutliple stocks, like "tsla", "goog", etc..

Could someone explain to me how to achieve this?

Kind Regards

Comment: iterate multiple stocks in url with above code...let me know you find difficult in using for loop

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Jeevan,

Currently I do not know how to achieve this since I am quite new to python coding, could you help me with that?

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

I have 1 issue now though, since I am downloading a ton of data, I have some pages that do not load because of an error.

How can i add something like "If error then skip"?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```py
import json
import requests
stk_list = ['aapl', 'tsla', 'goog']
for stk_name in stk_list:
    try:
        url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/{}/stats".format(stk_name)
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        data = (response['symbol'], response['float'])
        filename = 'float_{}.json'.format(stk_name)

        with open(filename, 'a+') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

I have 1 issue now though, since I am downloading a ton of data, I have some pages that do not load because of an error.

How can i add something like "If error then skip"?

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
import json

import requests


stocks = ['appl', 'goog']

base_url = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/{}/stats'

filename='float.json'

for stock in stocks:

    try:
        response = requests.get(base_url.format(stock))
    except:
        continue
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response_json = response.json()
        data = (response_json['symbol'], response_json['float'])

        with open(filename, 'a+') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment,

Unfortunately this code gives me the following error:

import json

import requests 


stocks = ['appl', ...]

base_url = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/{}/stats' 

filename='float.json'

for stock in stocks:

    try:
        response = requests.get(base_url.format(stock))
    except:
        continue
    if response.status_code == 200:

        data = (response.json()['symbol'], response['float'])

        with open(filename, 'a+') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)

Comment: i did some modification , you can try now